# Android: Read Zip file from specific directory

Tags: android, file, assets

I've got a Problem which I couldn't find an answer to for hours. I have a zip file in an Android Library Project, which I can't put in assets or raw directory (reading files from these directories is easy an no problem) due to several reasons. For now, I just put the zip file in the same source-package where it has to be read from.

My questions:

1) is it even possible to read files in android from other directories than assets and raw?
2) what is the path to files which are not in these directories. Let's say I put the zip file in a package namend a.source.package. When I sign my App and export it as an apk, the zip file is located at a/source/package/file.zip, but i cannot access it using this path.

I simply try to read the file like this:

```
ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(pathToZip))));
```

But get the following Excpetion:

```
06-08 11:02:03.612: W/System.err(3412): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/app/com.package.myapp.apk/com/my/package/tools/data.zip: open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you have to open the file as stream :- new ZipInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("data.zip"));

Comment: the zip file is create using winrar?

Comment: thanks Sudar Nimalan, that was the solution. it extracts the zip entries properly now :) Thank you very much!